# Spring Security oAuth complains about missing JWT verifier key even though it's defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am migrating an application from Spring Boot 1.5 to Spring Boot 2. This entails updating the oAuth2 library that the project uses, since as of Spring Boot 2, the `spring-security-oauth2` library has been replaced with `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` (as per my understanding).

Either ways, during startup my project complains about the JWT verifier key (required by oAuth2) as missing, even though I clearly have the URI to the key defined in my `application.yml` file, along with other oAuth2 config, as follows:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      userAuthorizationUri: ${uaa.url}/oauth/authorize
      accessTokenUri: ${uaa.url}/oauth/token
      clientId: ${security.oauth2.client.client-id}
      clientSecret: ${security.oauth2.client.client-secret}
    resource:
      jwt:
        keyUri: ${uaa.url}/oauth/token_key
```

The error that I get during startup is:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Binding to target org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties@468bb799 failed:

    Property: resourceServerProperties.tokenInfoUri
    Value: null
    Reason: Missing tokenInfoUri and userInfoUri and there is no JWT verifier key
```

This configuration worked perfectly until I was using Spring Boot 1.5.x, but after upgrading to Spring Boot 2 (and moving to the `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` library), I have started getting this problem.

I can access the key in my browser by visiting the URL defined as `keyUri: ${uaa.url}/oauth/token_key` in the config above, so it's clearly a valid URL. What could be the problem here?

Edit: One of the solutions I found online at several places was adding a dummy userInfoUri value, like this:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      userInfoUri: BUGFIX
```

I tried this, still getting the same error.

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug and a workaround might be to add a meaningless `userInfoUri` to your .yml file. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8565

Comment: @EdwinDiaz-Mendez Thanks, I tried that too, didn't work.

Comment: Okay. Question to you would be how come you are using a . properties file to configure a .yml file? Is it to avoid source control? Also are you sure there are no conflicts there?

Comment: Also please change `keyUri` to `key-uri` and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @EdwinDiaz-Mendez thanks, I already tried that too, didn't work. I think the `key-uri` format is to be followed only if you have a .properties file. I am using a .yml file instead, which needs a `keyUri` format.

Answer (score 2):

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: xxxx
      clientSecret: xxxx
      accessTokenUri: https://www/yyy.com/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server
      userAuthorizationUri: https://www/yyy.com/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server
      scope: openid profile email
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://www/yyy.com/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server
    sso:
      loginpath: /authorization-code/callback
```

in an application.yaml file did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        clientId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        clientSecret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        accessTokenUri: https:graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
        userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
        tokenName:  oauth_token
        authenticationScheme: query
        clientAuthenticationScheme: form
        scope: profile email
      resource:
        userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

I used this in my application.yml and it finally works. You just need to sublevel it with **spring:** (this worked for me).

Moreover, I think you should use spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client instead.

Comment: It looks like typo in `userInoUri`. Shouldn't it be `userInfoUri`?

Comment: @amra That's a typo indeed, edited the answer. Thanks!